# Memory optimization structure cpp

Tags: c++, memory-management, data-structures

I have to create a data structure for storing birthday of 1 trillion user. How to do that?

If I use a struct data type then it will need 6 bytes.

```
struct{

  int day,month,year;
}
```

so 6*1 trillion =  6 trillion bytes?

so is there any optimize way or others way to do that?

Comment: I doubt any architecture nowadays that could handle this amount of data would have a two-byte `int`. You could use `unsigned char` and a packed structure which would only require 3 bytes. Or just consider that the day needs 5 bits, the month 4 bits and the year… that depends on how you want to handle it, but if you store 1900 as 00, then probably 7 bits will be enough, so you can store the whole thing in a 16-bit `unsigned short`. **But:** *are you sure you will be able to fit **terabytes** in memory?*

Comment: There are much less than a trillion people on Earth, so the question looks useless. You need to be pragmatic when coding: there are about 1e10 people on Earth. So you could need only 3e10 bytes, e.g. a 32Gbyte machine, which is more reasonable.

Comment: *"I have to create a data structure for storing birthday of 1 trillion user."*  A C++ data structure?  I honestly doubt that.

Comment: You could create an array of 366 40-bit (or larger) integers , where the value of each entry is the number of people that have the birthday on that day

Answer (score 1):

Assuming 5 bit for day, 4 bit for month and 12 bit for year you need 21 bit per user. With padding to multiples of 8 bit, you have 24 bit = 3 byte per entry.

This means, you need something like 3 terabyte to store all your data (if I did not miscalculate).

Answer (score 0):

Based on Hannu's answer: (5 bits for day, 4 bits for month and 7 bits for year)

```
const unsigned long int n = 1e2;

// store (n * 2 bytes)
unsigned short birthdays[n];

static_assert( sizeof(short) == 2, "failure." );

// user input
int day = 31;   // requirement: 5 bits
int month = 12;  // requirement: 4 bits
int year = 127; // requirement: 7 bits. actual year = 1940(starting year) + 127 = 2067 (max year)

// store
// birthdays[0] = day + month * 32 + year * 512;
birthdays[0] = day + (month << 5) + (year << 9);

// how it looks
std::bitset<16> binary(birthdays[0]);
cout << "raw record: " << birthdays[0] << " (binary view = " << binary << ")" << endl;

// retrieve
day = (unsigned short)(birthdays[0] << 11) >> 11;
month = (unsigned short)(birthdays[0] << 7) >> 12;
year = (birthdays[0] >> 9) + 1940;

cout << "day = " << day << endl;
cout << "month = " << month << endl;
cout << "year = " << year << endl;
```

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8dcfabb763339ea5)

Comment: Bitfields apparently has some "implementation specific" behaviour, I therefore deleted my answer. Rewrite your code with shifts instead and it should be as fast as it can be on any processor.

Comment: @Hannu: now instead of multiplication bit shifts used. cheers.